# Three.js Trackball controls conflicting with html form

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I have some three.js  code with trackball controls enabled, and a form on top of the three.js canvas. This meant I was not able to select the form. I tried the answer gvien on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457487/three-js-conflict-camera-controls-with-a-textbox-in-a-scene) and now the controls dont work at all, but the input from does. However, the controls do work to degree in firefox, but the rotate speed is incredibly slow which I'm trouble changing. The controls won't work at all in chrome.

My code is [here](http://js.do/code/188520), and the relevant line is line 74.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use this: `controls.rotateSpeed = 4.0;` (default is `1.0`)

Comment: Alright, this took some time: https://jsfiddle.net/v9efuoLt/ I had to rewrite several things.

Comment: Thanks so much, that fixes everything.